# Plotting array which is randomly generated from nummpy.randn()

Tags: python, numpy, plot, random, gaussian

In the numpy documentation, it is said that randn generates numbers from a gaussian distribution, so after generating an array from randn if I plot it why am I not getting a bell curve?

```
x = np.linspace(1,1000,1000)
y = np.random.randn(1,1000)
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

[Output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP3Pt.png)

Comment: You have to do a histogramming of the numbers. Make bins, group by your random numbers in bins, divide by bin width and plot it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are plotting raw data.
Bell curve tells about probability(frequency in this case).
You need to plot frequency of unique samples.

This will show the bell curve you want.

```
plt.hist(y[0], bins=100);
```

`y[0]` to make data 1D.

More the  `bins`, the finer the results.